# How to update back(previous) screen in react-native by react-native-router -flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using react-native-router-flux in my application.

-I am using a parameter at my first screen and then i navigate to second screen.

-On the second screen i am updating that parameter which was used at my first screen.

-I want it to be updated when i navigate back to that screen (first screen).

How can i implement this functionality.

Thank You

Comment: Sharing data between views... Maybe using Redux ?

Comment: @Vinzzz I am not using Redux, then?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Vinzzz Can you please suggest, what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this Issue without using Redux.

Put the api calling statement of Screen First in a method(on First Screen) and passed it to second screen. On the second screen i called this method inside componentWillUnmount(). Its updating my first screen as i will be going back from screen second.

Answer (score 0):

@Vinzzz is right best solution is to use redux. But here how you can make this work without it.

When you navigate to another view you call action.OTHER_VIEW()

You can pass parameters to this function, which will be available via props in the component corresponding to your key : **"OTHER_VIEW"**

Here an example :

**routeA.js**

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  var _data = this.props.dataFromRouteB || "";
  this.state = {
    data : _data
  };
}

onPress(){
  action.ROUTE_B({dataFromRouteA: this.state.data}); // navigate to route B
}

render(){
  const {data} = {...this.state};
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>{data}</Text>
      <Button title="go to route B" onPress={()=> this.onPress()} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**routeB.js**

```
componentDidMount(){
  var a = this.props.dataFromRouteA; // a = ""
  a = "hello";
  action.ROUTE_A({dataFromRouteB:a}); // navigate to ROUTE_A , data will be available via  props
}
```

Comment: nice! Although, depending on how you build your navigation from A to B, A might not be unmounted while B is displayed, no?

Comment: Can i do it using react lifecycle methods?
If yes then please suggest which one i should use?

Comment: Vinzzz, i don't know how navigation is implemented in this lib. @Kailash can you be more specific. What do you want to do in the lifecycle method  ? Call action.ROUTE_X() ?

Comment: @DanielGabor , I am implementing chat functionality, and i want to update message unread count as i will be navigating back from message read screen.

Comment: I see what you try to do, i recommend you to use redux whenever you need to share data between component, its gonna be much simpler

Comment: =>Screen A ( I called API here, and used that data here and also passed data to Screen B.)

=> Screen B (I used the data received from Screen A, then i navigate to screen C )

=> Screen C ( Here i updated data. this updated data will be fetched by Screen A API.  So now when i will navigate back to Screen B, here i want updated data. )

@DanielGabor this is problem actually.