# How to redirect back and refresh the parent view

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hello everyone I am new to react-native.

React native V 0.61
React navigation V 5.x

I have a search bar for a weather API once it is clicked you arrive to the temperature list.

If you type an invalid city, I want to be redirected back with an error message. My problem is that I do not know how to do this because my parent component is not getting updated!

SEARCH.JS

```
export default class Search extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        city: 'Liège',
        error: ''
    }
}

setCity(city){
    this.setState({city})
}

submit(){
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Result', {state: this.state});
}

render(){
    if (this.state.error != '') {
        var error = this.state.error;
    } else {
        var error = 'hello world';
    }

    return (
        <View style={GlobalStyle.container}>
            <TextInput
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setCity(text)}
                onSubmitEditing={() => this.submit()}
                style={GlobalStyle.input}
                value={this.state.city}
            />
            <Button color={GlobalStyle.color} onPress={() => this.submit()} title="Lancé recherche"/>
            <Text>{error}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}}
```

LIST.JS

```
export default class List extends React.Component {
constructor (props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        city: this.props.route.params.state.city,
        result: null
    }
    this.fetchWeather();
}

fetchWeather(){
    axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='+this.state.city+'&appid=MYKEY&units=metric&lang=fr')
        .then((response) => {
            this.props.route.params.state.error = '';
            this.setState({result: response.data})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // console.log(error.response.data.message);
            // console.log(this.props.navigation.setOptions());
            // this.props.navigation.setParams.onReturn({city: this.props.route.params.state, error: error.response.data.message});
            // this.props.state.error = 'errror';
            this.props.route.params.state.error = error.response.data.message; 
            // console.log(this.props.route.params.state.error);
            this.props.navigation.goBack();
            // this.props.navigation.navigate('Search', {error: error.response.data.message});

        });
}

render(){
    if(this.state.result === null){
        return (
            <ActivityIndicator color={GlobalStyle.color} size="large"/>
        );
    }else{
        return (
            <FlatList 
                data={this.state.result.list}
                renderItem={({item}) => <WeatherRow day={item}/>}
                keyExtractor={item => item.dt.toString()}
            />
        );
    }

}}
```

Thank you for your help and have a good day.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664551/how-to-update-backprevious-screen-in-react-native-by-react-native-router-flux

It might be a solution for you.

Comment: create a function in Search.js which will set all the data to your default values, then pass that function in the navigation statement, like you have passed state in submit().  and on error call that function before calling goback().

Answer (score 0):

In Search.js add

```
onBackToHome =() => {

this.setState({
        city: 'Liège',
        error: ''
    })
}

submit(){
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Result', {state: this.state, backToRefresh: this.onBackToHome});
}
```

Then in List.js

```
//Add this line just above this.props.navigation.goBack()

this.props.navigation.state.params.backToRefresh();
```